# Export django model as pdf from admin model

Tags: python, django, pdf

I would like to export my model to a pdf file directly from my model admin using reportlab.

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    invoice_date = models.DateField('Invoice date')
    invoice_sent = models.BooleanField()
    invoice_paid = models.BooleanField()
```

And my model admin:

```
class InvoiceItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def pdf_version(self, obj):
    ## how to call my reportlab view here ??
```

Please help,
M.

Comment: What have you tried? There are demos in the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use actions! I'm taking it you already created your reportlab view and you just want to redirect to it with your model items. so create a function like this (outside of any class):

```
def pdf_version(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    url = '/your_pdf_url/?pks=' + ','.join([q.pk for q in queryset])
    HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Then in the admin:

```
class InvoiceItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [pdf_version]
```

In the example I am using GET data to allow more than one report at a time, because that seems reasonable, but you can obviously change this however you'd like. It's as easy as that. Also [check out the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) for futher details

Comment: Thank you both, your hints were very helpful.